# Use Of Take and switch rxjs operator in below code

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

Below is a code from the article https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/ for implementing JWT token refreshing in angular.
I want to know, why switchmap and take operators are used in the below code eventhough I think they will work fine without them.
I know the uses of both these operators but need to know the use case here.

```
private isRefreshing = false;
private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  if (!this.isRefreshing) {
    this.isRefreshing = true;
    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

    return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
      switchMap((token: any) => {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.jwt);
        return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.jwt));
      }));

  } else {
    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter(token => token != null),
      take(1),
      switchMap(jwt => {
        return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
      }));
  }
}
```

Comment: switchMap in the if block or else block you talking about?

Comment: switchmap in  both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first block you will need to get the refresh token before you pass to the next handler so you either need a `switchMap` or `mergeMap` to execute the observable. There is no need to `take(1)` in the first block because `this.authService.refreshToken()` will complete in one execution.

In the second block since behavior subject is a continuous stream, you only want to get the latest value once, without `take(1)` the subsequent handler will still attached to the stream and run whenever `this.refreshTokenSubject.next()` has called. However i suspect the code has a potential memory leak issue, IMO take(1)should be placed be before `filter`.

Comment: token refreshing is working fine, but all the request coming while `this.isRefreshing` is true is not getting completed successfully.

whats that issue?

Comment: if filter didnt found matching request then it just drop that request or postpone it to another time where token is available?

Comment: It will not emit and wait for token turn not null, so there's the memory leak issue. To be honest, i think there's room to rewrite the code to make it more functional. isRreshing really breaks the beauty

Comment: I have some http calls in ngoInit and i loaded the component by removing the token.
Then component is loading fine by refreshing the token but some http calls in ngoInit are not working. thats why i asked that will filter wait for a token availabilty.

can u please suggest some good article to read if current implementation is bad?

Comment: token refreshing is working fine but some http calls not executing succesfully in ngoninit

Comment: I'll add some code there when i have time see if i can help

Comment: sure , please sent me link

Comment: Could you setup a simple stackbliz with the interceptors ?

Comment: let me try
iam not sure since there are some http calls and i may implement the backend also

Comment: I think here switchMap in first block is used to subscribe to only the latest event and cancels or drops the previous one?

Comment: yes, but this event will only fire once. so mergeMap switchMap, concatMap all the same effect here

Comment: Thats what doubted me a lot. Now cleared. I think a normal Map can also be used?

Comment: You cannot use normal map, map doesn't execute handler.next()

Comment: I have done a mistake by setting `this.isRefreshing = false` inside else block which resulted in multiple refreshtoken calls and some of them cancelled.
I think the latest one will only work since Iam using switchmap operator

Comment: Can u please help me on a doubt?

Now my codes are working like on first http 401 reponse the token went for refreshing after setting `tokenrefreshing== true`. 
if any other http 401 comes at that times they will go to else block and check filter for token availabilty.

what if token is not processed at that time ? the htpp call will drop or just wait till token availabilty?
how filter actually works here?